# How to use JGit to get the URL of origin?

Tags: git, jgit

How to use JGit to get the URL of the **origin** remote?

I am using JGit and I want to execute

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The configuration of a git repository can be accessed through `Repository::getConfig()`. The returned type is a `StoredConfig`.

In order to get the URL of the *origin* remote, use this snippet

```java
String url = repository.getConfig().getString("remote", "origin", "url");
```

The class `ConfigConstants` lists a set of frequently used section names and value names.

Comment: Is there any documentation on what values are possible for getString()?

Comment: See the [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation for syntax and the configuration settings understood by native Git. However, JGit does not understand all of these. in doubt, you would need to verify if JGit can handle a certain setting or not.